# Gravitational potential energy (explanation)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality

Hello to you dear person reading, I need your help to please explain me this :

$${\displaystyle \Phi (P)={\frac {-GmM}{\|OP\|}}+K}{\displaystyle \Phi (P)={\frac {-GmM}{\|OP\|}}+K}$$

(I haven't learned this yet because im younger than 15)

All I know is that $K = 0$ because the potential energy is infinit which makes it $0$ but it could also be arbitrarily positive.

(If you would like more information on this equation, you can visit the negative energy on wikipedia for more details. (gravitational potential energy)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: We use dollar signs to set off MathJax.  I added them for you.  It looks like you have two copies of the solution equation.  Please delete one.  It is not clear what your question is.  Are you asking about the derivation of the solution of the differential equation?  That is shown in many classical mechanics textbooks and too long for this forum.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help, I apologize for my mistakes I will try not to repeat them in the future. I have deleted the copy of the equation and yes I am asking about the derivation of the solution of the differential equation and I will look into the machanics textbooks. Yet again thank you.